# Replace Subquery with a Join in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

How can I rewrite the below query so that the subquery becomes part of join? Or any other better ways?

```
Declare @CR varchar(32)

SELECT count(*)
FROM [dbo].[TableC]
    INNER JOIN  [dbo].[TableCS] ON [TableCS].[CSI] = [TableC].[CSI]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableI] ON [TableI].TableIId = [TableC].[TableIId]
WHERE [TableC].[CR] = @CR
    AND [TableI].[POR] = (SELECT POR FROM TableI inner join [TableC] on TableI.TableIId =  [TableC].TableIId and [TableC].CR = @CR)
    AND [TableCS].[Consider] = 1
```

Comment: This is a question more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than stackoverflow. Please refer to [this comment for more information about how to phrase questions and where to post them](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778)

Comment: What is `[case].TableIId` *(In your sub-query)* meant to refer to?

Comment: [case].TableIId is an auto increment primarykey that I am doing join on.

Comment: @SHK - And yet your query has ***no*** table in it named  `[case]` or aliased to `[case]`.  At present it's an error.

Comment: Apologise I have fix that error, please look at the query again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF POR is a column of TableC then...

```
Declare @CR varchar(32)

SELECT count(*)
        FROM [dbo].[TableC]
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[TableCS] ON [TableCS].[CSI] = [TableC].[CSI]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableI] ON [TableI].TableIId = [TableC].[TableIId] and [TableC].CR = @CR AND [TableI].[POR]= [TableC].POR
        WHERE [TableC].[CR] = @CR
        AND [TableCS].[Consider] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to transpose the sub-query in to your main query using aliases...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) 
FROM
  [dbo].[TableC]
INNER JOIN 
  [dbo].[TableCS]
    ON [TableCS].[CSI] = [TableC].[CSI]
INNER JOIN
  [dbo].[TableI]
    ON [TableI].TableIId = [TableC].[TableIId]
(
    TableI   AliasedTableI
  INNER JOIN
    TableC   AliasedTableC
      ON  AliasedTableI.TableIId = AliasedTableC.TableIId
      AND AliasedTableC.CR       = @CR
)
  ON  AliasedTableI.POR = TableI.POR
WHERE
      [TableC].[CR] = @CR
  AND [TableCS].[ConsiderInExistenceChecks] = 1
```

That's unlikely to be the best and final refactor.  But without knowing your schema or business rules it's the only safe one I can write for you.